# Arrow, tab, backspace keys are not working in Swing JTextField,JPasswordField components

Tags: swing, jar, arrow-keys

I'am developing a Swing desktop application. In my login panel, there are JTextField components. I'am using Netbeans IDE 7.2.1 and Java 1.6. Update 31. When debugging and running project from Netbeans IDE, all keyboard functions, keys are working greatly, but in the case of running *jar file from command line or double-clicking on it, the arrow, tab, backspace keys also mouse-right click not working in JTextField component.
I want to use if there exists any default Keyboard focus manager utilities, etc., i do not want to implement keylisteners for each of keys.

Comment: For tab key, for each component tab indexes must set, netbeans do this automatically i think, i use a vector of components hiearchically and implement abstract class FocusTraversalPolicy http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/misc/FocusTraversalDemoProject/src/misc/FocusTraversalDemo.java

Answer (score 1):

Found the ":set bs=2" option in jVi.

In Netbeans, go to Tools->Options->jVi Config->Buffer Modifications->backspace->2. That's it.